# Widgets in game programming

Tags: widget

friends!
I am novice in game programming.
I work with PopCap Framework v1.3.
I read some tutorials about it and all the time I see word "widget".
What does word "widget" mean within PopCap Framework? Does word "widget" mean the same within entire game-development?

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary.com defines widget as;

> widg·et/ˈwijit/ Noun:
>
> ```
> A small gadget or mechanical device.
> An application, or a component of an interface, 
> that enables a user to perform a function or access a service.
> ```

In programming these tend to be things like buttons and combo boxes, things which can add to the Aesthetics.

Comment: I have found such definition:
"PopCap uses something called a Widget. A Widget is a self contained unit that has it’s own update, drawing, and input processing methods. These widgets are managed by something called a Widget Manager which allows us to manage multiple widgets at one time."
http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/PopCap:Tutorials:Breakout:Part1
Is it similar to your definition?

Answer (score 0):

Widgets are graphical elements such as Buttons, Frames, Dialog Boxes, etc. Widgets have some particular behaviour/logic, e.g. a Button widget reacts on clicking, a dialog box widget can be moved around etc. Widgets can be combined together to build more complex widgets, e.g. a dialog box widget consists of a frame, text and button widgets.

Comment: I have found such definition:
"PopCap uses something called a Widget. A Widget is a self contained unit that has it’s own update, drawing, and input processing methods. These widgets are managed by something called a Widget Manager which allows us to manage multiple widgets at one time."
http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/PopCap:Tutorials:Breakout:Part1
Is it similar to your definition?